# Question About ECB,CBC,CFB,CTR usage and where

Tags: encryption, cryptography

So i have a general question about the Usage and where ECB,CBC,CFB,CTR could be used  like in what situations would you guys consider them useful?

just the general like for example a Bank etc.

any examples would be cool

Answer (score 0):

ECB is insecure and should not be used as is.  The classic demonstration is the [ECB Linux Penguin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_(ECB)).  It is included because the other modes are built on top of ECB, so the code is present anyway.

The other modes use different methods to avoid the problem with ECB.  CBC is probably the most common general mode.  CTR needs a little more care setting up to ensure that the Nonce/Key combination is unique, but once set up it can be parallelised, which CBC cannot.

None of these modes include message authentication, which would have to be done separately with a MAC -- Message Authentication Code.  Other modern modes, such as GCM -- Galois Counter Mode -- include authentication without needing a separate MAC.

Comment: so where would you say they could be used? or would be used? like what kind of systems would use these to encrypt?

Answer (score 0):

ECB is used everywhere all the time. It is the raw cryptographic primitive that is the AES permutation.  It is not secure on its own as the same input always produces the same output. Algorithms such as CBC, CTR and GCM all use ECB internally.

CBC uses padding to make the message an exact number of cipher blocks long. This means that an observer does not know the precise length of the message without decrypting it. Most other schemes leak the message length. The use of padding introduces a vulnerability to padding oracle attacks. Padding oracle attacks can be blocked by use on Message Authentication Codes (MACs) which assert that a given cipher text is authentic. You can’t do a padding oracle attack without changing the cipher text and the MAC prevents that.

CTR encrypts a block counter and XORs it with the equivalent block of the message. This means you can access any part of the plain text without decrypting the whole message. However it is extremely vulnerable to the reuse of an IV (initialisation vector).

GCM is quick hack to fix a message protocol that forgot to include a proper MAC. It is built on CTR and shares its quirks. The MAC is only 128bits, when 256 bits would normally be required. The MAC is also verified after the entire message has been processed which means developers often process the message before it is validated which reduces the effectiveness of GCM even further.

OFB is a way of using CBC hardware to perform stream encryption and like CTR is particularly vulnerable to repeated IVs, and is weak if used with partial block feedback.

CFB has no well known vulnerabilities. It does reveal the message length though, and whilst repeated IVs are not quite so catastrophic, they still need to be avoided.

Which cipher mode to use where is a matter of matching quirks to requirements, but if I had to recommend a particular one I would say:

1. Use CFB
2. Include a MAC of the cipher text in your protocol, e.g. HMAC with SHA512/256.